# SQL statement query with nested clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For presentation purposes I modify the table names and fields and simplify the SQL problem:

We have a table named `A` with only 2 columns:

```
Name   ServiceReceived
=========================
Mr A   Medical
Mr A   Dental
Mr A   HealthCare
Mr A   Special1
Mr B   Dental
Mr B   HealthCare
Mr C   Medical
Mr C   Dental
Mr C   HealthCare
Mr C   Special
Mr C   Special2
```

I need a list of all people who revised medical or dental.

And ALSO received one or two of Special1 and Special2

I tried

```
where ServiceReceived in ('medical', 'dental')
  and ServiceReceived in ('Special1', 'Special2')
```

But this does not work.

```
======================================
```

Expected Results:(As you see MrB is not there, since he does not have Special1 or Special2

```
 Name   ServiceReceived
    =========================
    Mr A   Medical
    Mr A   Dental
    Mr A   HealthCare
    Mr A   Special1 
    Mr C   Medical
    Mr C   Dental
    Mr C   HealthCare
    Mr C   Special
    Mr C   Special2
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @jarlh I will further explain the expected results in question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```sql
    select t.*
    from t
    group by Name
    having sum(case when ServiceRecived in ('Medical', 'Dental') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
           sum(case when ServiceRecived in ('Special1', 'Special2') then 1 else 0 end) between 1 and 2;
```

If you want to see all the details, you can use `join`, `in` or `exists`:

```sql
    select t.*
    from t
    where t.name in (select Name
                     from t
                     group by Name
                     having sum(case when ServiceRecived in ('Medical', 'Dental') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                            sum(case when ServiceRecived in ('Special1', 'Special2') then 1 else 0 end) between 1 and 2
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I fit this into my actual SQL and will let you know!

Comment: Your SQL correctly eliminate MrB. But only give me result as MRA and MrB.I want also to see All  of their service names.

Comment: That's it! My real SQL code is far very complex. but your solution applies to that also.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
Select Name 
from 
(
Select Name,
       Sum(Case when ServiceRequested = 'Medical' then 1 else 0 end) as Medical,
       Sum(Case when ServiceRequested = 'Dental' then 1 else 0 end) as Dental,
       Sum(Case when ServiceRequested IN ('Special1','Special2') then 1 else 0 end) as Specials
from [dbo].[Services]
Group by Name
)s
Where  ( Medical >= 1 or Dental >= 1 ) AND Specials >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following solution works with the SQL server INTERSECT table operator.

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM T 
WHERE ServiceReceived IN ('medical', 'dental') 
INTERSECT 
SELECT NAME 
FROM T WHERE 
ServiceReceived IN ('Special1', 'Special2')
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM A
WHERE
    NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM A AS A2 WHERE A2.ServiceReceived IN ('medical', 'dental'))
    AND NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM A AS A2 WHERE A2.ServiceReceived IN ('Special1', 'Special2'))
```

Comment: What is A Here?  if you are referring to TableA, your query still does even run.

Comment: What is 'SELECT NAME FROM A AS A2 WHERE A2.ServiceReceive' ????this SQL is not correct.

Comment: @SNash, I revised Chaim`s answer trying to make it clearer.

Comment: @SNash, The query works perfectly fine. Only Mr A and Mr C are pulling in the result set. If you want to see distinct values just add a DISTINCT clause. And 'A' is the table name, just like it is described in the question "We have a table named A"